# Drag drop replace value from on select to other select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have two select from one select i want to drag the value to the other select drop-down.On drag of value i want to have the feature of drag drop and replace .But i am not getting how can we do this

I want this feature like this http://jsfiddle.net/EpxHE/149/

**HTML**

```
<td><select multiple=""  style="width: 147px;" id="list" name="list">
<option value ="1">One</option>
<option value ="2">Two</option>
<option value ="3">Three</option>
<option value ="4">Four</option>
<option value ="5">Five</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select id="grp" style="width: 147px;" name="grp" multiple="" >


</select>

</td>
```

From the `list` i want to drag the values to `grp` drop down.If we override the values from `list` to `grp` than it will replace the values in the drop drop and also we can drag the values to from `grp` to `list`